Confusion about the strength and quality of available WiFi APNs
My application uses a WiFi connection to work.
It scans the available APNs and connects to the strongest one available.
Testing here at home, I have a Virgin Router (using a Deco Mesh).
I issue this command:
nmcli dev wifi
I get this back:
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       5C:62:8B:CA:2E:9C  dev            Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  100     â–‚â–„â–†â–ˆ  WPA2      
        62:62:8B:CA:2E:9C  --             Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  100     â–‚â–„â–†â–ˆ  WPA2      
        5C:62:8B:CA:2B:DB  dev            Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  44      â–‚â–„__  WPA2      
        FC:77:7B:65:06:08  RealiseMotion  Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  42      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2 
        40:F2:01:51:AB:02  PLUSNET-6SWC   Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  42      â–‚â–„__  WPA2      
        62:62:8B:CA:2B:DB  --             Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  37      â–‚â–„__  WPA2      
        72:97:41:57:50:1A  --             Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  37      â–‚â–„__  WPA2      
        72:97:41:57:50:1F  EE WiFi        Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  34      â–‚â–„__  --        
        70:97:41:57:50:1E  BT-6RCKK9      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  32      â–‚â–„__  WPA2

My home connection is 'dev' and you can see it is listed twice but with different BSSIDs. So,
1st question:  Which one do I use to measure strength and quality?
2nd question:  When I issue this command:
nmcli con up Dev
But out or the 1 channels it listed above which one will it use?

@AndrewSimpson Point is that it makes our lives easier trying to answer your question if you just give us the output you got in text rather than an image. I suggest running nmcli dev wifi > output.txt as it will output what you normally get to a text file where you can copy and paste it to the question.

You said your home connection is "dev"; is there more than one access point using that SSID? It looks like dev has two mesh nodes. So you are measuring strength and quality for both.

@Paul. Thanks for commenting.  I AM using 2 mesh nodes.  The 1st one is directly attached to my virgin router downstairs. The other is right here, upstairs in my office.  This is a normal and basic configuration, I need to know how to specifically address/connect to the stronger one.  thanks

Looking at your first question, you may want to just do the one with the highest signal strength as it will give you a better performance on your network. In your case, the network with the BSSID 5C:62:8B:CA:2E:9C seems to be the best one, so you should use that one.
About your second question regards to nmcli, nmcli will try to connect to the best dev network. For example, if one dev connection has a higher signal than the other dev, then it will connect to that one. Looking at the output you provided, nmcli will likely connect to 5C:62:8B:CA:2E:9C due to its signal strength.
If you want to connect to a specific network, you can input its bssid with its ssid and password like this
nmcli dev wifi connect AP_SSID password YOUR_PASSWORD bssid AP_BSSID
